# Extrude along normals problem

Tags: normals, extrude

Im trying to extrude this edges along normals over Z axis. Median point selected and Z is pointing correctly as shown in this picture.

[image: Correct normals]

But as soon as I press E to extrude and Z Z to use normals restriction, normals Z axis changes to this:

[image: Incorrect normals?]

So extrusion is not what expected.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just press E, it should automatically lock to gimbal Z axis.

Comment: Select the edge loop around the hole and fill it with *F*. Set the transformation orientation type to *Normal* and then extrude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer by Paul Gonet in the comments. Thank you so much.

Select the edge loop around the hole and fill it with F. Set the transformation orientation type to Normal and then extrude. – Paul Gonet

That worked as expected. Thanks a lot, Paul Gonet.

Comment: Although I'm sure Paul doesn't mind, the general etiquette would be to allow Paul a chance to write up the answer himself (and get any points associated with the answer being accepted/upvoted).

Comment: Yes. I will wait for Paul to write the answer. And mark his answer as the solution.

I thought I could mark his comment but I was wrong.

So I will wait for his answer.

Comment: You have already written an answer, which you can accept, I was just mentioning it for in future.

Comment: @dogday feel free to accept you answer :)